# Schedule Oozie workflow through Java API

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

Is it possible to schedule Oozie workflow *dynamically*? That is, to specify parameters through Java API instead of configuration files?

For example, I would like to be able to schedule workflow execution every day at 10 PM, but to specify that time through web interface, since it could be changed. How to do that?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are getting to. Do you want to use an external scheduler to submit Oozie workflows (directly, or thru a one-shot coordinator)? Or do you want to reset scheduling rules of a running Oozie coordinator (e.g. because of Dailight Saving Times messing with Oozie UTC crontab)?

Comment: My system has user which can specify when should jobs run through a web interface. They are not aware of Oozie and don't know about Hadoop underneath. So, they should be able to log into the system and say - "do this thing" every day at X time. I want to do that using Oozie. Is that possible and how to do it?

Comment: Well, yes, submit a Coordinator with crontab-like scheduling. But beware of UTC time conversion, especially if your country uses DST. And if the user ever changes his/her mind, kill the Coordinator and re-create it with new scheduling rule.

Comment: Could you please point me to some reference which explains how to perform such scheduling in Java code? Well, that could be challenging, since users can come from different countries. Is there some kind of standard solution for this kind of problems with different time zones?

Comment: We don't use the Java client, only the CLI. Anyway the logic is the same: "submit" a list of properties containing the path to a XML file defining, either a Workflow, or a Coordinator (w/ a property containing the path to a XML defining a Workflow). Look into the Oozie docs for Coordinator.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use the following :

```
public class Oozie {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OozieClient wc = new OozieClient("http://oozieserver:11000/oozie");

        Properties conf = wc.createConfiguration();

        conf.setProperty("nameNode", "hdfs://namenode:8020");
        conf.setProperty("jobTracker", "resourcemanager:8032");
        conf.setProperty("queueName", "default");
        conf.setProperty("oozie.libpath", "${nameNode}/user/oozie/share/lib");
        conf.setProperty("oozie.use.system.libpath", "true");
        conf.setProperty("oozie.wf.rerun.failnodes", "true");

        conf.setProperty("oozieProjectRoot",
                "${nameNode}/user/bijoy/oozieProject");
        conf.setProperty("appPath",
                "${oozieProjectRoot}/workflowJavaMainAction");
        conf.setProperty(OozieClient.APP_PATH, "${appPath}");

        conf.setProperty("inputDir", "${oozieProjectRoot}/data/*/*/*/*/*");
        conf.setProperty("outputDir", "${appPath}/output");

        try {
            String jobId = wc.run(conf);
            System.out.println("Workflow job, " + jobId + " submitted");

            while (wc.getJobInfo(jobId).getStatus() == WorkflowJob.Status.RUNNING) {
                System.out.println("Workflow job running ...");
                Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
            }
            System.out.println("Workflow job completed ...");
            System.out.println(wc.getJobInfo(jobId));
        } catch (Exception r) {
            System.out.println("Errors " + r.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
}
```